# Ubuntu SDK: How can I use PyQt for developing Ubuntu Touch apps?

Tags: python, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, pyqt

I've heard that it's possible, can you give me some pointers on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [pyotherside](https://github.com/thp/pyotherside) that is already packaged for ubuntu as `pyotherside` (for trusty you can just manually download and install the utopic package, or build from sources). You only need to have this installed in your `$QML2_IMPORT_PATH/io/thp/pyotherside`.

Then on Qml side you can just load the `Python` component, and do the magic. See the examples and read the [documentation](http://pyotherside.readthedocs.org/).